# Coin Change Problem with Dynamic Programming

Tags: python, dynamic-programming, coin-change

This is my code regarding the **Coin Change Problem** for print the total number of ways for a set of coins and the target amount

```
def coin_change(coins,amount):
    table=[0 for k in range(amount+1)]
    table[0]=1
    for coin in coins:
        for x in range(coin,amount+1):
            table[x] = table[x]+ table[x-coin]
        print(table)  

    return table[amount]
```

I want to know that is there any method to print those ways with the same dynamic programming solution (with the help of an inner constructed table or any other)

for example if a set of coins are [1,3,5] and target amount is 6
so there are total of 4 ways possible.
[[1,1,1,1,1,1,],[1,1,1,3],[3,3],[1,5]]
I want this way's list as an output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can readily adapt your current code to produce a list solutions.

```
def coin_change(coins,amount):
    table=[[] for k in range(amount+1)]
    table[0].append([]) # or table[0] = [[]], if you prefer
    for coin in coins:
        for x in range(coin,amount+1):
            table[x].extend(solution + [coin] for solution in table[x-coin])
        print(table)  

    return table[amount]
```

The `table` variable is now a list of lists of lists, with the inner lists being the combinations of coins that add up to a given value, rather than just a count of how many of those combinations there are. Instead of adding up the new combinations, I use a generator expression that we pass to `extend`.

Comment: Thanks a lot for this solution :)

Comment: Is there any way to be in contact?

Answer (score 1):

Answer edited per your requirement:

```
def combine(parent, me):
    if len(parent) == 0:
        return [[me]]
    new_list = []
    for entry in parent:
        new_list.append(entry + [me])
    return new_list


def get_ways(amount, coins):
    table = [0 for k in range(amount + 1)]
    table[0] = 1
    ways = [[] for _ in range(amount + 1)]
    for coin in coins:
        for x in range(coin, amount + 1):
            table[x] = table[x] + table[x - coin]
            ways[x].extend(combine(ways[x - coin], coin))
    print(ways[amount])
    return table[amount]


print(get_ways(6, [1, 3, 5]))
```

The output:

```
[[1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1], [1, 1, 1, 3], [3, 3], [1, 5]]
4
```

Comment: please go through the edited post with adding an example, what is the expected output.

Comment: Thank you so much for your solution :)

Answer (score 0):

```
    Arrays.sort(coins);
    int dp[]=new int [amount+1];
    Arrays.fill(dp,amount+1);
    dp[0]=0;
    for(int i=0;i<=amount;i++){
        for(int j=0;j<coins.length;j++){
            
            if(coins[j]<=i){
                
                dp[i]=Math.min(dp[i], 1+dp[i-coins[j]]);
                
            }
            else
                break;
            
        }
        
        
    }
   
    return dp[amount]>amount ? -1: dp[amount];
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question improves its long-term value.